# filter Foreach-Object results with multiple conditions in Powershell not working

Tags: powershell, powershell-7.0

I'm trying to filter a list of changed files in git using Powershell 7. I want only the file paths that begin with 'packages' or 'database'. When I run the code, the results are not filtered and everything is returned. How would I get the filtering to work? I'm new to Powershell scripting.

Here is my code:

```
$editedFiles = git diff HEAD [git commit id] --name-only
$editedFiles | ForEach-Object {
    $sepIndex = $_.IndexOf('/')
    if($sepIndex -gt 0 -and ($_ -contains 'packages' -or 'database')) {
        Write-Output $_      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of things to watch out for here:

`-contains` is a *collection containment operator* - for strings, you'll want either the `-like` wildcard comparison operator:

```
$_ -like "*packages*"
```

or the `-match` regex operator:

```
$_ -match 'package'
```

The other thing to watch out for here is the `-or` operator - it only takes *boolean* operands (`$true`/`$false`), and if you pass it anything else, it'll *convert* the operands to `[bool]` if necessary.

That means that the following kind of statement:

```
$(<# any expression, really #>) -or 'non-empty string'
```

ALWAYS returns `$true` - because a non-empty string evaluates to `$true` when converted to `[bool]`.

Instead, you'll want to change two separate comparisons:

```
$_ -like '*packages*' -or $_ -like '*database*'
```

Alternatively, you can use the `-match` operator *once*, by using an alternation (`|`):

```
$_ -match 'package|database'
```

And end up with something like:

```
$editedFiles | ForEach-Object {
    $sepIndex = $_.IndexOf('/')
    if($sepIndex -gt 0 -and $_ -match 'package|database') {
        Write-Output $_      
    }
}
```

---

If filtering is all you intend to do in the `ForEach-Object` block, you might as well use `Where-Object` - it's designed *exactly* for that :)

```
$editedFiles | Where-Object {
    $_.IndexOf('/') -gt 0 -and $_ -match 'package|database'
}
```

Comment: Your Where-Object example is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks so much.